# Достаточный для хранения 2x числа тип

Tags: c++, типы

У меня есть число. Как получить тип, который может хранить это число, умноженное на 2, если число имеет не "максимальный" тип? Например, число `i` типа `__int32`, тогда `2*i` всегда можем хранить в `__int64`. Как узнать, что нужен `__int64`?

Comment: Откуда вы знаете, что в int 32 бита?

Comment: 1. Двоичный логарифм полученого числа показывает какая разрядность нужна этому числу.

Comment: @nick_n_a можете написать метафункцию?

Comment: @vp_arth пусть будет `__int32` тогда

Comment: 2. Когда overflow получите (при определённых опциях компилятора) - тогда вам не хватило разрядов.

Comment: @nick_n_a можно для простоты считать, что разрядов хватает, т.е. тип не максимальный

Comment: На практике используют сравнение. Например если  -128 <= i  <=127 то вам хватит 8 бит. Числа -128,127,8 в любом стравочнике по типам можно найти.

Comment: Если вход неотрицательный - для выхода хватит uint32

Comment: @nick_n_a я понимаю, сколько бит мне нужно), как метафункцию для задачи написать?)

Comment: Вопрос неоднозначно сформулирован. Что имеется в виду? Как *во время выполнения* узнать, переполнитсля ли `2*i` для конкретного `i`? Или как *во время компиляции* безусловно просто найти следующий больший целочисленный тип для данного типа `T`?

Comment: @AnT в 3 раз пишу: считаем, что при продвижении нам хватит рязрядов, т.е. на вход подается byte, short, int (положительный int64, если мы можем проверку сделать, если нет, то нет); но кроме простой спецификации не знаю как продвинуть вверх (из ваших вариантом номер 2 получается)

Comment: Нужна шаблонная функция с типом результата большим, чем тип аргумента?

Comment: Автор 10 раз написал слово **метафункция** вопрос следовало бы переименовать "Какая метафункция получения разрядности числа" - ответ - метафункции в даном случае не используют. Возможно вас интерисует sizeof(i) - оно даст размер i в байтах. Больше метакод вам ничего не даст.

Comment: @nick_n_a под метафункцией я понимаю функцию, работающую на этапе компиляции, в c++ с рефлексией туговато

Comment: Приведите фрагмент кода где у вас проблема - так мы не угадаем вашу идею.

Comment: @vp_arth ну даа

Comment: @nick_n_a что непонятного? `int i; metafuntion<decltype(i)> j;`

Comment: Может вам нужно это `template<typename T> int __inline getsize(){ return sizeof(T)*8; } `

Comment: @nick_n_a это рантайм :-/

Comment: @nick_n_a `int i; int j = getsize<decltype(i)>()` теперь нам надо делать проверку в рантайме и создавать тип там же

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну навскидку можно просто вручную создать (платформенно-зависимый) маппинг размеров типов на следующий по размеру тип

```
template <size_t N> struct next_type_impl;

template <> next_type_impl<8> {
  // Предполагая 16-битный `short`
  typedef short signed_type;
  typedef unsigned short unsigned_type;
};

template <> next_type_impl<16> {
  // Предполагая 32-битный `int`
  typedef int signed_type;
  typedef unsigned unsigned_type;
};

// И т.д.

template <typename T> next_type {
  typedef typename next_type_impl<sizeof(T)>::signed_type signed_type;
  typedef typename next_type_impl<sizeof(T)>::unsigned_type unsigned_type;
};
```

А далее в коде

```
next_type<decltype(i)>::signed_type larger_i;
```

Все это можно реализовать элегантнее и гибче, но примерная идея такова.

---

Например, один раз задав руками последовательность целочисленных типов, можно уже автоматически платформенно-независимо выбирать тип большего размера, если он существует

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct next_int { typedef T type; };
template <> struct next_int<signed char> { typedef short type; };
template <> struct next_int<short> { typedef int type; };
template <> struct next_int<int> { typedef long type; };
template <> struct next_int<long> { typedef long long type; };

/**********/

template <typename T> struct next_larger_int;

template <typename T, bool stop = false> struct next_larger_int_cond
{
  typedef typename next_larger_int<typename next_int<T>::type>::type type;
};

template <typename T> struct next_larger_int_cond<T, true>
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T> struct next_larger_int
{
  typedef typename next_int<T>::type next;
  typedef typename next_larger_int_cond<next, (sizeof(next) > sizeof(T)) || std::is_same<T, next>::value>::type type;
};


int main()
{
  std::cout <<
    sizeof(next_larger_int<signed char>::type) << std::endl <<
    sizeof(next_larger_int<short>::type) << std::endl <<
    sizeof(next_larger_int<int>::type) << std::endl <<
    sizeof(next_larger_int<long>::type) << std::endl <<
    sizeof(next_larger_int<long long>::type) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: да, это то, что я хочу, а можно как-нибудь по количеству бит получить нужный тип без спецификаций или это в принципе невозможно?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то в C++ ничего не говорится о конкретных размерах типов. Так что `int` может оказаться и таким же, как `__int64`.

Разве что смотрите в `<cstdint>` типы с точными размерами.

Comment: почему это не делают в любой кроссплатформенной программе?

Comment: @user238446: Такие вопросы в кроссплатформанных программах обычно решаются не "автоматически" через метапрограммирование, а вручную, через набор `typedef` для числовых типов. Типа пусть у нас будет тип `data_type` для хранения основных данных и тип `mul_data_type` для выполнения умножения между двумя `data_type`. Правильные типы выставляются руками для каждой платформы.